# Feynman integration trick

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will moving differentiation from inside, to outside an integral, change the result?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resul)

In his book 'Surely you're joking mr Feynman' author mentions a trick he found in a book while still in high school. He calls it 'differentiation under integral sign' and claims that it  helped him solve integrals that maths majors and professors were struggling with.

Could someone describe this trick?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign.

Comment: There is some discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resul

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate of 12909.

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50837

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this "trick" is one that "math majors and professors were struggling with."