# Example of $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx \neq \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

A sufficient condition $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx = \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$ holds is [Will moving differentiation from inside, to outside an integral, change the result?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu),

or
[When do the partial derivative and integral of different variables commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38256/when-do-the-partial-derivative-and-integral-of-different-variables-commute?noredirect=1&lq=1).

On the other hand, an example of $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx \neq \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$ is
[Derivative commuting over integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8711/derivative-commuting-over-integral).

This example, $f$ is discontinuous function.

I want to know example of continuous function $f$ such that

- $x \mapsto f(t, x)$ is integrable for all $t$,
- $t \mapsto f(t, x)$ is differentiable for all $x$,
- $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx \ $  and $\  \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$ exist in $\mathbb{R}$, and
- $\int \frac{df}{dt}dx \neq \frac{d}{dt} \int fdx$.

i.e. an integrable function $g$ such that $$\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t, x) \right| \le g(x).$$

doesn't exist. ([Will moving differentiation from inside, to outside an integral, change the result?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu))

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/q/436316/31729

Comment: What about a slightly modified function $f:[0,+\infty)^2\to\Bbb R$ defined as $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}e^{y-x},&x>y\ge 0\\-e^{x-y},&0\le x\le y\end{cases}\space ?$$

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much.

Comment: @Invisible Thank you for your comment. Isn’t  $f$ discontinuous?