# Why can't I interchange Integration and Differentiation here?

Tags: integration

Consider $f(x,y)=y^3e^{-y^2x}$ and define $F(y) =\int_0^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$

We have that $F'(0)\not = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)dx$

in the spoiler there is how I got this, in case I made a mistake there

> We calculate $F'(0)$ essentially using Monotone convergence theorem we can show that,
> for $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} $,   $F(y)=y$ moreover $F(0)=0$ so $F'(0)=1$

Now, I want to understand which hypothesis of Theorem 2 [at this page](http://planetmath.org/DifferentiationUnderIntegralSign.html/) does not hold.
Instead of the third hypothesys at the link, though, I use this weacker hypothesis, which is still enough:

"For each $b \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an open interval $b\in J$ and an integrable function over $(0, \infty)$ , $g(x)$ such that $| \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)| \leq g(x)$ for every $y\in J$ and $\forall x$"

Now, the first hypothesis certainly holds as
$\forall  y, \ x\rightarrow f(x,y)$ is integrable $(0,\infty)$ by comparison with $e^{-kx}$ for appropriate positive value of $k$

Moreover $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ exists everywhere...

So is the last hypothesis to be problematic but I can't see how as I can bound $y$ in $J$ and then just use some linear combination of $e^{-kx}$ and $ xe^{-lx}$ for suitable $k,l$  as they are both integrable over $(0,\infty)$...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The theorem says if you can bound $f_y(x,y)$ with an integrable function $g(x)$, that is
$$ |f_y(x,y)|\leq |g(x)|, $$ 
then you can change the order of differentiation and integration.

Comment: yes but I think you can weacken this condition by bounding $f_y$, for each $b \in \mathbb{R}$ on an open interval containing $b$ (and for all values of x)!

Comment: or do you think I can just say that my $f$ does not respect this condition and hence why the theorem doesn't work? it feels like cheating!

Comment: any idea? the theorem I refer to is not the one you quote but more similar to Theorem 3 in this page http://planetmath.org/DifferentiationUnderIntegralSign.html

Comment: @Moritz See [this answer of Qiaochu](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/12911/1543) for a very general statement.