# How to derive the formula to estimate the stock price probability distribution from call option prices?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to understand the derivation that
$$\phi(S)=\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial K^2}$$
from 
$$C(K) = \int_{0}^{\infty} max(S-K,0)\phi(S)dS$$
where $\phi$ is a probability density function.

(This equality is relevant for example to estimate transition densities for a European call from the prices of call options.)

---

*Edit*: the following does not work since the derivative of $max(S-K,0)$ is not continuous:

I see that I get this result by differentiating two times with respect to K, but only if I can exchange the differential operator with the integral operator ds:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}(\int_{0}^{\infty} max(S-K,0)\phi(S)dS$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(S)\frac{\partial}{\partial K}( max(S-K,0))dS$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(S)(-1)dS\quad\text{if } K<S, \quad 0 \text{ otherwise}$$
If I can do this, the desired result appears, since the dirac function has derivative 1 exactly at $K=S$.

Comment: You need to specify further properties of the function $\phi$.

Comment: this smells like blackscholes, is $\phi$ the distribution function of the price, i.e. log normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$C(S,K)=\int_{K}^{\infty}(S-K)\phi(S)\;dS$$
and so assuming $\phi(S)$ and $S\phi(S)$ is integrable we're fine.  However, since $K$ appears in both the limits and the integrand, we have boundary terms to deal with and therefore we need [Leibniz's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule); incidentally however, the boundary terms are all zero in this case.  We have then
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}=\int_{K}^{\infty}-\phi(S)\;dS.$$
Differentiating a second time we get (this time just using the fundamental theorem of calculus, which is a special case of Leibniz's rule)
$$\frac{\partial^{2}C}{\partial K^{2}}=-(-\phi(K)) = \phi(K)$$
as desired.

Comment: very nice. i learnt something today. The first observation is exceptionally crucial.

Comment: What you have not done is justifying the limit swap. do you know how to do that? curiously, i asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673146/what-is-the-requirement-on-f-for-the-fracddx-intx-0fx-xdx-to-exis question. I think the link to Leibniz rule answer this.

Comment: Removing the max by changing the boundary of integration, didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: @Taylor I think before applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, it is neccesary to exchange the integral boundaries, so that the minus sign vanishes, right?

Comment: @Raphael No, the fundamental theorem works fine with the lower integral limit variable. You have - for continuous $f$ - $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^b f(t)\,dt = - f(x).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer But the minus sign in the last step above should be removed, right?

Comment: @Raphael It need not. Set $f(t) = -\phi(t)$ in the above (and replace $x$ with $K$), the differentiation leads to $-(-\phi(K))$ then. Of course, you can also write it $\int_\infty^K \phi(S)\,dS$ to get rid of the minus sign, but that's optional.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your answers so far! I'm somehow stuck, so one more question: The second derivative, should it be $\phi$ or $-\phi$?

Comment: @Raphael $\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}$? That's $\phi$. Taylor made a mistake at the end, since we differentiate the integral with respect to the lower bound, that differentiation produces a minus sign, and that cancels the one we got from the first differentiation.

Comment: @Raphael But the differentiation produces the integrand evaluated at the integral limit, that is $K$ here. By the way, something is wrong in the question, you write $$C(S,K) = \int_0^\infty \max (S-K,0)\phi(S)\,ds,$$ which doesn't make sense. If $s = S$, the integral doesn't depend on $S$, so it ought to be $C(K)$ alone. If $s\neq S$, what is $S$, and what $s$, something in the integral must depend on $s$ then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13132/discussion-between-raphael-and-daniel-fischer)

Comment: Sorry, wrote the answer too hastily and made a sign mistake at the end.  Thanks Daniel Fischer for the edit.

Comment: @Raphael.  The part where I mention "...as long as $\phi$ and $S\phi$ are integrable we're fine" is the justification for differentiation under the integral sign (see the link for Leibniz's rule).

Comment: @Taylor thanks, understood.