# Automatic way to derive $∫_0^x f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d} t$

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Correct me if I'm wrong, but
\begin{align}
F(x) = ∫_a^b f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d} t &\implies F'(x) = ∫_a^b \frac{∂f}{∂t} \,\mathrm{d} t, \qquad \text{and} \\
G(x) = ∫_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d} t &\implies G'(x) = f(x).
\end{align}
But is there any general “*formula*” to derive this function
$$
F(x) = ∫_a^x f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d} t,
$$
or, in a more general way
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \biggl( ∫_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apply [Leibniz' integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (a.k.a. differentiation under the integral sign),

> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{a(x)} ^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t
> =f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)} ^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

which in your case gives

$$F'(x)=f(x,x)+\int_a ^x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

**Edit:** As asked by a user, the precise conditions for Leibniz' integral rule to hold for $t\in[t_1,t_2]$ are

- $a,b$ are $C^1$ on $[t_1,t_2]$
- $f$ is $C^1$ on $\{(x,t): t\in [t_1,t_2], x\in[a(t),b(t)]\}$

(see, e.g., Kaplan: *Advanced Calculus*, Chpt. 4.9)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673146/exact-smoothness-condition-necessary-for-differentiation-under-integration-sign I have a bounty open for this. I think this answer would be a good candidate for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost identitical to the question I asked and answered myself here:

[Exact smoothness condition necessary for differentiation under integration sign to hold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673146/what-is-the-requirement-on-f-for-the-fracddx-intx-0fx-xdx-to-exis)

You need some additional smoothness condition, e.g. the partial derivative $\partial_xf(x,t)$ to be continuous. The wiki link is actually pretty dreadful as the smooth conditions are not clearly stated. I wonder if someone can give an authentic source.

Comment: Thanks for the critique, I added the conditions and a reference to my answer.