# Gradient of a function involving integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Statement of the problem

Let $F(x,y)=\iint_{R_{xy}} e^{(u-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}dudv$ where $R_{xy}$ is the region $[0,x]\times[0,y]$. Calculate $\nabla F(1,1)$

The attempt at a solution

I know that $\nabla F(1,1)=(\dfrac{\partial F(1,1)}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial F(1,1)}{\partial y})$.

I am going to calculate the first partial derivative since the other one can be calculated in a similar way.

$\dfrac{\partial F (x,y)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^y\int_0^x e^{(u-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}dudv$. Now, I don't know if the following step is legitimate:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^y\int_0^x e^{(u-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}dudv=\int_0^y [\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^x e^{(u-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}du]dv$

If that last step was correct, I would like to know how to justify it.

Now, by the fundamental theorem of calculus I know that

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^x e^{(u-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}du=e^{(x-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}$

Using this I get

$\dfrac{\partial F (x,y)}{\partial x}=\int_0^y e^{(x-1)}e^{(v^2-v)}dv=e^{(x-1)}\int_0^y e^{(v^2-v)}dv$

Here I got stuck, I've tried to calculate this integral but I couldn't.

Have I done something wrong up to now and maybe that's why I am having trouble with this integral? I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step you want to justify is actually a pretty subtle thing, known as [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). If you're new to calculations like this, then you probably aren't expected to justify it, but [this answer of Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12911/26369) tells you some conditions under which it's valid.

You applied the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus correctly. The integral you got stuck on [has no elementary antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), and doesn't really simplify to something in terms of simple constants when you plug in $(1,1)$ as you have to do to get $\frac{\partial F(1,1)}{\partial x}$. So after you plug in $(1,1)$ and simplify the $e^{x-1}$ part, there's nothing more you can really do with that piece symbolically.

The $y$ partial should work out a bit more nicely.

Comment: I never heard of "differentiation under integral sign" (Leibniz integral rule) until now. Thanks for your answer!