# How to take derivatives of a convolution when the kernel's derivative is in the distribution sense?

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, convolution

I came need to take the derivative of the following convolution:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}f(y) \, dy
$$

However, the derivative of the kernel only exists in the sense of distributions, i.e.
$$
-\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}=2\delta(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}-e^{-|x-y|}
$$

My question is: According to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu), one cannot directly take the derivatives under the integral sign. So for my situation here, how am I supposed to do the differentiation?

Comment: What is the domain of your convolution operator?

Comment: You missed a factor of $2$ in the derivative of $\text{sgn}(x-y)$.  I took the liberty of editing.  I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: Under what hypotheses does the identity $(f*g)'(x) = (f'*g)(x)=(f*g')(x)$ hold? And are those hypotheses satisfied here? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Split the integral as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sgn} (x-y)e^{-|x-y|}f(y) \, dy = \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-y)}f(y)\,dy-\int_x^{\infty} e^{(x-y)}f(y) \, dy$$ and use [Leibnitz's Rule for differentiating under an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

**SPOILER ALERT:  SCROLL OVER SHADED AREA TO SEE ANSWER**

> $$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sgn} (x-y)e^{-|x-y|}f(y) \, dy&=f(x)-\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-y)}f(y)\,dy+f(x)-\int_x^{\infty} e^{(x-y)}f(y) \, dy\\\\&=2f(x)-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x-y|}f(y) \, dy\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @ Dr. MV Yes your answer matches what I formally obtained. However, I am just wondering whether there is an explanation to validate my completely formal way of taking distributional derivatives under the convolution.

Comment: @user52919 There is an explanation, but it obviously does not fall into classical analysis.  Rather, it relies on the theory of [Generalized Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function), or [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).  Here, we have $-\frac{d}{dx}\langle g(x),f \rangle  =-\langle g'(x),f \rangle =\langle g(x),f' \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}f'(y)dy$.  Carrying out this last operation yields the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)e^{-|x|}$ and let $\delta$ be Dirac's delta "function".  The problem is to find $(g*f)'(x)$.

$$
(g*f)'(x) = \underbrace{(\delta'*(g*f))(x) = ((\delta'*f)*g)(x)} = (f'*g)(x). \tag 1
$$

The thing $\underbrace{\text{in the middle}}$ has no meaning outside the context of some theory in which we can speak of $\delta'$. But the equality $$(g*f)'(x)=(f'*g)(x) \tag 2$$ is meaningful, and so can be true or false, outside such a context.  If the whole chain of equalities $(1)$ is true in the Dirac context, then can $(2)$ be false in the context in which it can be understood without knowing of Dirac?

Here I'd say I'm rusty in that stuff and would crack open a book and remind myself of which hypotheses are needed for which conclusions to hold and ask whether those are satisfied.

That's how I would initially approach the problem.

Comment: In the theory of distributions, $\delta'$ is defined such that $\langle \delta',f\rangle=-\langle \delta,f'\rangle=-f(0)$.  So, one can proceed along those lines in one chooses.  The OP is asking, I believe, for some way forward for integrating under the integral sign.   One can use classical analysis in a straightforward way here and not rely on Generalized Functions.