# To what extent $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t,x)\, dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(t,x)\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assume $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t,x)\, dt$ exists for every $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$. Then, to what extent, the following equation holds?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t,x)\, dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(t,x) \,dt.$$

Comment: Its true for all  $f(t,x)$, remember the integral is just a sum and the derivative operator is linear.

Comment: Here is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury The essence of this problem is the interchange of two limits (derivative and integral). It seems that the function should be uniformly continuous. I am not sure.

Comment: @Siminore I am not sure if Leibniz integral holds for improper integrals.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/will-moving-differentiation-from-inside-to-outside-an-integral-change-the-resu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Lebesgue integral we have this theorem ([Integración de funciones de varias variables](https://www.amazon.es/Integraci%C3%B3n-funciones-variables-Ciencia-T%C3%A9cnica/dp/843681665X)):

Let be $(X,\mu)$ a measure space, $J\subset\Bbb R$ an interval.

Exists $g$ integrable s.t. $|f(x,t)|\le g(x)$ for all $t\in J$ and almost all $x\in X$.

Exists $\partial_t f(x,t)$ for all $t\in J$ and almost all $x\in X$.

Exists $h$ integrable s.t. $|\partial_t f(x,t)|\le h(x)$ for all $t\in J$ and almost all $x\in X$.

Then
$$F(t) = \int_X f(x,t)\,d\mu(x)$$
is derivable and
$$F'(t) = \int_X \partial_t f(x,t)\,d\mu(x).$$

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the answer what I want. Even though it is not a necessary and sufficient condition, it is helpful enough for my research.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf) answers your question for the finite case in Theorems 1 and 2. Extending it to the unbounded case is achieved in Theorems 3-5.

Without retyping all the proofs, $f$ and $\frac{d}{dx}f$ need to be continuous, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}f$ need to be [uniformly convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence).

Comment: Thanks very much for your nice answer. [Yesterday I gave you +1, and I still wait for other answers that could state it in measure theory. Still thanks very much for your answer!]