# How find this $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{(2x)}}{x^2+4}dx$

Tags: integration

Find this integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\sin{(2x)}}{x^2+4}dx$$

let $x=2t$,
then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t\sin{(4t)}}{(t^2+1)}dt$$
then
$$I=1/2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(4t)}d\ln{(t^2+1)}$$
then I can't.

This problem have without residue  methods?

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of this [Functions defined by integrals (problem 10.23 from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/functions-defined-by-integrals-problem-10-23-from-apostols-mathematical-analys)

We have that
$$
    F(y) = \int \frac{\sin(xy)}{x(x^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x 
         = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-y})
$$
A generalization of your integral is given as
$$
    G(a,y) = \int \frac{\sin(xy)}{x(x^2+a^2)}\mathrm{d}x 
           = a^{-2} F(ay) 
           = \frac{\pi}{2a^2}(1-e^{-ay})
$$
Differentiating twice yield
$$
       \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 G}{\mathrm{d}y^2} 
    = -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(xy)}{x^2+a^2}
    = - \frac{\pi}{2}    e^{-ay}
$$
Hence
$$
      \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\sin{(2x)}}{x^2+4}\mathrm{d}x 
    = -G''(2,2) 
    = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-4}
$$
Where $G''(a,y)$ means differentiation with respect to $y$.