# solving the integral $ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin xt}{x(x^2+1)} dx $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How to solve the following integral by differential equations techniques?
$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin xt}{x(x^2+1)} dx $$

Comment: Are you familiar with theorems of complex analysis (applications of residue theorems) for real integration? Also, does $t$ have any restrictions?

Comment: I think that the convolution transform is useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/functions-defined-by-integrals-problem-10-23-from-apostols-mathematical-analys and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63275/completing-the-differential-equation-from-exercise-10-23-in-tom-apostols-mathe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recalling the Laplace transform

> $$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt. $$

We can use it to solve the problem. Taking Laplace transform with respect to $t$ gives

> $$ f(t)=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin xt}{x(x^2+1)} dx \implies F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(s^2+x^2)}  . $$

The last integral can be evaluated using partial fraction techniques (see below) to give

> $$ \implies F(s) = \frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {\pi }{s \left( s+1 \right) }}. $$

Now, we can find the inverse Laplace transform using [convolution technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253613/convolution-laplace-transform) as

> $$ f(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{t} e^{-\tau}d\tau = \frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-t}). $$

Alternatively, one can use partial fraction technique

> $$  \frac{\pi}{2}\frac {1}{s(s+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}\right). $$

to find the inverse Laplace transform

**Notes:**

> 1) The Laplace transform of $\sin(az)$ with respect to $z$ is
>   $$ {\frac {a}{{s}^{2}+{a}^{2}}}. $$
>
> 2) $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(s^2+x^2)}={\frac {1}{ \left( {s}^{2}+{x}^{2} \right)  \left(1- {s}^{2} \right)}}-{\frac {1}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)\left(1- {s}^{2} \right) }}.$$
>
> 3) Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s}$ and $\frac{1}{1+s}$ are given by
>   $$  1,\quad e^{-t} $$
>   respectively.

Comment: Where is the mistake in my (mistaken) solution? For $t=1$,
$$
\int _0^\infty{\sin x\over x(x^2+1)}dx={1\over2}\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{ix}\over x(x^2+1)}dx\\
={1\over2}\Im2\pi i\text{Res}({e^{ix}\over x(x^2+1)},i)
$$
Since $i$ is a simple pole,
$$
=\Im\pi i\cdot {e^{ix}\over x(x^2+1)}|_{x=i}=\\
\Im \pi i{e^{-1}\over i\cdot2i}=\Im\pi i{e^{-1}\over-2}={-\pi \over2e}
$$

I know how to get the propriate solution which is ${\pi(e-1)}\over 2e$ but I don't understand where is the mistake in this answer?

Answer (score 6):

This integral is custom-made for analysis via integration in the complex plane.  I'm not sure if you have any familiarity with the following concepts (e.g., residues), but I am going to evaluate it here in this fashion for completeness.

Consider the following integral in the complex plane:

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i z t}}{z (z^2+1)}$$

where $C$ is the following contour:

[image]

Thus, we avoid the pole at $z=0$ by deforming into the upper half plane.  The contour integral is thus equal to

$$\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} dx \frac{e^{i x t}}{x (x^2+1)} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{i \epsilon e^{i \phi} t}}{\epsilon e^{i \phi} (\epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}+1)}+ \\ \int_{\epsilon}^{R} dx \frac{e^{i x t}}{x (x^2+1)} +i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{i R e^{i \theta} t}}{R e^{i \theta} (R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+1)} $$

We take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$.  Note that the second integral becomes $-i \pi$.  The fourth integral vanishes when $t \gt 0$; its magnitude is bounded by

$$\frac{2}{R^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R t \sin{\theta}} \le  \frac{2}{R^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R t \theta/\pi}  \le \frac{\pi}{R^3 t}$$

On the other hand, the contour integral is equal to, by the residue theorem, $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=i$ (i.e., the only pole within the contour $C$).  Thus

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i x t}}{x (x^2+1)} - i \pi = i 2 \pi \frac{e^{-t}}{2 i^2} $$

or

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i x t}}{x (x^2+1)} = i \pi \left ( 1 - e^{-t}\right )$$

Now, take the imaginary part of both sides; the principal value disappears and we get, for $t \gt 0$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin{ x t}}{x (x^2+1)} =  \frac{\pi}{2} \left ( 1 - e^{-t}\right )$$

Comment: Excellent.Thanks,but you solved it by complex analysis techniques.

Comment: @Angel: You're welcome, and I am aware of what you asked for vs what I provided.  But again, some integrals are just tailor-made for contour integration, and I just wanted to express that.