# Evaluate the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\sin ^2 (x) \over x^2 (x^2 + 1)}\:dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Can we evaluate the integral using [Jordan lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma#Application_of_Jordan.27s_lemma)?
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\sin ^2 (x) \over x^2 (x^2 + 1)}\:dx$$

What de we do if removeable singularity occurs at the path of integration?

Comment: Have you tried an approach like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34436/evaluating-the-contour-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin3xx3-math?rq=1 ?

Comment: thanks for hint!! I'll try and let you know!!

Comment: @Siminore i didn't understand the concept of introducing $-2$ at the end
Brain just stopped working 
:(((((

Comment: It follows from $\sin^3 z = (\sin 3z - 3\sin z)/4$, in that case.

Comment: @Siminore can you explain a bit about Robjohn's method on [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160022/integration-by-means-of-complex-analysis)?

Comment: @celtschk so how do I evaluate above integral? I am more interested  in understanding How robjohn did on This Question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160022/integration-by-means-of-complex-analysis

Comment: Robjohn uses the fact the the integral of an analytic function along a closed path is always zero. When the path contains no singular point, you can deform it, as long as the new path contains no singular point of the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using $\sin^2(z)=\frac12(1-\cos(2z))$, you should be able to handle this in much the same way as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160022/integration-by-means-of-complex-analysis/160099#160099).

---

**Details** (modified from the answer mentioned above)

Since $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2z^2}=1$, the singularity of the integrand near $z=0$ is removable. Therefore, since the integrand vanishes for $z$ within $\frac12$ of the real axis as $|z|\to\infty$ and there are no singularities within $\frac12$ of the real axis, the integral does not change when shifting the path of integration from $z=t$ to $z=t-\frac{i}{2}$.

Now we can break up the integral as
$$
\int_{-\infty-i/2}^{\infty-i/2}\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2z^2(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z
=\frac14\int_{\gamma^+}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}\mathrm{d}z
+\frac14\int_{\gamma^-}\frac{1-e^{-2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}\mathrm{d}z\tag{1}
$$
where $\gamma^+$ and $\gamma^-$ are as depicted below:

$\hspace{4.6cm}$[image: path of integration]

$\gamma^+$ circles two singularities ($z=0$ and $z=i$) clockwise, and $\gamma^-$ circles one singularity ($z=-i$) counter-clockwise.

All of the singularities are simple, so to get the residue at $z=z_0$, we just need to multiply by $z-z_0$ and taking $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0}$

At $z=0$ the residue of $\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$ is $-2i$

At $z=i$ the residue of $\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$ is $\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{-2}}{-2i}$

At $z=-i$ the residue of $\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{-2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$ is $\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2i}$

Putting these together with $(1)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^2(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac{2\pi i}{4}\left(-2i+\frac{1-e^{-2}}{-2i}\right)-\frac{2\pi i}{4}\left(\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2i}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2-\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2}-\frac{1-e^{-2}}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2+\frac{\pi}{2e^2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks man!! you are lifesaver!!

Answer (score 4):

Taking 
$$C_R:=[-R,-\epsilon]\cup\left(\gamma_\epsilon:=\{z=\epsilon e^{it}\;\;|\;\;0\leq t\leq \pi\}\right)\cup [\epsilon,R]\cup\left(\gamma_R:=\{z=Re^{it}\;\;|\;\;0\leq t\leq \pi\}\right)$$
$$f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$$
we get
$$\oint_{C_R}\frac{1-e^{2iz}\,dz}{z^2(z^2+1)}=2\pi i\,Res_{z=i}(f)=2\pi i\frac{1-e^{-2}}{i^2(2i)}=-\pi\left(1-e^{-2}\right)$$
But
$$\oint_{C_R}f\,dz=\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} f\,dx\,-\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}f\,dz+\int_\epsilon^Rf\,dx+\int_{\gamma_R}f\,dz$$
Using now the nice lemma in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-0-pole-and/184874#184874) , we get
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}f(z)dz=-i\pi\,Res_{z=0}(f)=-i\pi(-2i)=-2\pi$$
And either using Jordan's lemma or directly:
$$\left|\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz\right|\leq \frac{1+e^{-2R\sin t}}{R^2(R^2-1)}\pi R\xrightarrow [R\to\infty]{}0$$
So passing to the limit when $\epsilon\to 0\,\,,\,\,R\to\infty\,$ and using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2\sin^2x\,dx}{x^2(x^2+1)}=2\pi-\pi(1-e^{-2})=\pi\left(1+\frac{1}{e^2}\right)\Longrightarrow $$
$$\Longrightarrow\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x\,dx}{x^2(x^2+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint, note that $ \cos(2x)=1-2\sin(x)^2 $, this suggest to consider the integral

$$ \int_{C} \frac{ {\rm e}^{2 i z} - 1 }{ z^2 (z^2 + 1)} dz \,.$$