# Integral $\int\frac{(\sin(x))^2}{x^2+1} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have no idea of variable changement to use or other to calculate this integral :

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(\sin(x))^2}{x^2+1}\,dx 
$$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+sin%28x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29) gives me the result but really no idea ...

I seek a calculus without residues theorem or other big theorems like it because I didn't learn them.. so just by part or by variable changement if possible sure..

Thanks in advance,

Shadock

Comment: The integrand function does not have a primitive in terms of elementary functions, but the integral can be computed through the residue theorem or the Laplace transform.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for differentiation under the integral.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE how to differentiate under the integral with just one variable?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/272623/170231) might be useful if you can reduce the power of sine. The linked problem is also worked out using the Laplace transform, which might be easier to follow.

Comment: Ok so I just have to learn the Laplace transform and his inverse ? Is there just one transformation and inverse or a lot of possibilities ? @Euler....IS_ALIVE how to differentiate with just one variable ?

Comment: @Shadock You would have to cleverly introduce a parameter.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE like sin(xt)^2 or sin²(x)/(x^2+t^2) ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a proof with the residue theorem. We have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2(1+x^2)}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x^2},$$
but:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \Re\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{2iz}}{1+z^2}\,dz=\Re\left(2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2iz}}{1+z^2},z=i\right)\right),$$
so:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{e^2}\tag{1} $$
and:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2e}\sinh 1.$$
With a probabilistic argument, $(1)$ follows from the fact that the CF of the standard [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) is $e^{-|t|}$. To prove it, it is enough to show that:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t}\cos(nt)\,dx = \frac{1}{1+n^2}\tag{2}$$
holds by integration by parts.

Comment: The key step is just to prove the identity on the third line. I bet there are many proof of it on MSE.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: now added also a probabilistic argument.

Comment: Oh my gosh !!! I just understand the first line and the beginning of the second :/

Answer (score 1):

I particularly like Jack's hint concerning the Laplace transform. Write
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
Then,
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{I(a)\right\}=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2+1}e^{-as}\,da\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+1)(s^3+4sx^2)}\,dx$$

Comment: (+1) This further simplifies if we take $\cos(ax)$ in place of $\sin^2(ax)$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it's not clear to me how working out the last equality is any easier that evaluating the original integral.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition yields $$-\frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+1}+\frac{2s}{s^2+4}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{4x^2+s^2}=\frac{\pi}{2(s^2+4)}-\frac{\pi}{s(s^2+4)}$$ Finding the inverse transform is fairly simple, and that gives an expression equivalent to $I(a)$. (Barring any silly mistakes on my part)

Comment: @user170231 what is the inverse Laplace of $\pi / (2s^2+4s)$ ?

Comment: You can determine that with some more partial fraction decomp