# Find the definite integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{cos(xt)}{1+t^2}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve this using Laplace transforms by using the relation

$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x} dx = \int_0^\infty F(p) dp$

where $F(p) = L[f(x)]$

But recasting it transforms it into a very messy integral.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272622/integral-evaluation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-ax-pi-1x2dx?noredirect=1&lq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Let's consider the  [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of $\displaystyle I(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx$. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(I(a)\right)(s)&=\mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx\right)(s)
\\& = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}e^{-as}\:da\:dx
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{(x^2+1)(s^2+x^2)}\;{dx} 
\\&= \frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}
\end{aligned}\tag1
$$giving
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0, \tag2$$