# Residue Theorem complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{2i \sqrt[3]x + e^{2ix}}{x^2+4}$$ .

I want to calculate integral for this . I know I have to use residue theorem to get simplified version of this but How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Observe first that
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x^2+4}
$$
is an odd function, and hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}\,dx}{x^2+4}=0.$$

Also, $$\frac{\sin 2x}{x^2+4},$$ is an odd function. Hence, it remains to calculate
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos 2x\,dx}{x^2+4}.
$$

See relative [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-with) and [also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272622/integral-evaluation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-ax-pi-1x2dx).

Comment: Why do you say that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is an odd function of $x$? (It's not if the principal value is used.)