# Evaluating the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(x-\frac{1}{x} \right)}{1+x^{2}} \ dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

I'm curious about the proper way to evaluate $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(x-\frac{1}{x} \right)}{1+x^{2}} \, dx =  \text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i(x- \frac{1}{x})}}{1+x^{2}} \, dx$$ using contour integration.

If I let $f(z) = \frac{e^{i(z- \frac{1}{z})}}{1+z^{2}}$, there is an essential singularity at the origin.

So if I integrate around a closed semicircle in the upper half-plane, the contour goes right through the singularity.

Can you indent a contour around an essential singularity?

Comment: You can indent your contour around the essential singularity at $0$ in the upper half plane. It doesn't matter whether $0$ is an essentially singularity or not. What matter is on the infinitesimal semi-circle around $0$ in the upper half plane, $| e^{i(z - \frac{1}{z})} | \le 1$. You will only get into trouble if your place the semi-circle in lower half plane.

Comment: So am I calculating a Cauchy principal value?

Comment: In certain sense, yes. You are calculating the Cauchy principal value. However, since $\cos(x - \frac{1}{x})$ remains bounded as $x \to 0$, the original integral over $\mathbb{R}$ exists and equal to the Cauchy principal value you just calculated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the symmetry:
$$
   \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
Now, making the change of variables $u = x-\frac{1}{x}$ there are two solutions:
$$
    x = x_{\pm}(u) = \frac{u}{2} \pm \sqrt{1 + \frac{u^2}{4}}
$$
Changing variables:
$$
  2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \cos(u)}{1+x_+(u)^2} \frac{x_+^\prime(u)}{2} \mathrm{d}u + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \cos(u)}{1+x_-(u)^2} \frac{x_-^\prime(u)}{2} \mathrm{d}u
$$
Combining these, with some simple algebra:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x &=&  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \cos(u)}{4+u^2} \mathrm{d}u = \\ &=& \Re  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 \mathrm{e}^{i u}}{4+u^2} \mathrm{d}u = \Re\left( 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}_{u=2i} \frac{2 \mathrm{e}^{i u}}{4+u^2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{\mathrm{e}^2}
\end{eqnarray} $$
Note, that the above substitution is related to the Cauchy-Schlömilch substitution (see [arXiv:1004.2445](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2445)).

---

Numerical check:

```
In[68]:= N[
  NIntegrate[Cos[x - 1/x]/(1 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]] == Pi/E^2

Out[68]= True
```

Comment: My experience is that it generally works as long as there are no branch-cuts involved.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x-1/x = t$. Now note that $t^2 = x^2 + \dfrac1{x^2} -2 \implies \left(x+\dfrac1x \right)^2 = t^2+4$. We then get that
$$\left(1 + \dfrac1{x^2} \right)dx = dt \implies \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} dt = \dfrac{dt}{\left(x+1/x \right)^2} = \dfrac{dt}{t^2+4}$$
Hence, the integral becomes
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x-1/x)}{x^2+1} dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x-1/x)}{x^2+1} dx = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(t)}{t^2+4} dt = \dfrac{\pi}{e^2}$$
where the last integral can be obtained from the post below.

[Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ without using complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/)

Comment: Your answer appears to be be off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @user40314 Thanks. That was because I made a mistake. The change of variable needs to be done a bit carefully since the function is not one to one on the entire real line (It is one to one for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$). Now I have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the residue calculation is sufficient. Note that

$$\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{i(z-z^{-1})}}{1+z^2} \times ir e^{i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta\right|$$

is bounded by

$$r\left|\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{1}{r} \times \sin\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta\right| < r\pi \to 0$$

Hence indenting the contour around the origin makes for **no difference between the real integral and the complex one**. Then note the integrand is meromorphic within the region with this boundary. The behaviour outside of this contour is irrelevant, essential singularities or otherwise.

Thus the residue at $i$, $\boxed{\pi/e^2}$, is the correct value.

The argument does not work for e.g. a contour passing through the origin since the function is non-analytic at the origin, so Cauchy's theorem does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{x -1/x}\over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x} =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{x -1/x}\over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \sr{x\ =\ \expo{\theta}}{=} &
2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{2\sinh\pars{\theta}}\over 1 + \expo{2\theta}}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{2\sinh\pars{\theta}}\over 1 + \sinh^{2}{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] \sr{\sinh\pars{\theta}\ =\ t}{=} & \
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2t}\over 1 + t^{2}}\,\dd t
=
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2t\ic}\over \pars{t + \ic}\pars{t - \ic}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
\Re\pars{2\pi\ic\,{\expo{-2} \over 2\ic}} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{\pi \over \expo{2}}} \approx 0.4252\\ &
\end{align}