# Is there always an alternative way to compute integral other than complex integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Sometimes we have to compute integrals that are not easy to calculate so that we need to depend on the method of complex integrals like the residue method. But I became curious about possibility of alternative method of evaluation of integrals other than complex integrals.

For example, do we have an ordinary, 'real' method of integral evaluation method for calculating
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1-\alpha}\cos(\omega x)dx$$
or
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos(ax)\over{b^2-x^2}}dx$$
?
In this question I mean 'real' method in the sense that one does not visit the complex plane to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Are you sure you meant a minus sign in the denominator of second one instead of plus? :P

Comment: I know how to evaluate the second one using real method. Is Laplace or Fourier transform OK?

Comment: Yes, actually these integrals came up from Fourier transform. But if I have to look up the Laplace transform table, I don't think that's a real solution. Is there a good real method?

Comment: Following the Pranav's comment, are sure about the minus sign in the denominator?

Comment: Well, yes. Actually I originally was interested in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{iax}\over {b^2-(x-ic)^2}}dx$.

Comment: The second integral only exists as a Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1 <a <2$,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{1-a} \cos (wx)\ dx &= w^{a-2} \int_{0}^{\infty} u ^{1-a} \cos (u) \ du \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos (u) \ t^{a-2} e^{-ut} \ dt \ du
 \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a-2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos (u)e^{-tu} \ du \ dt  \\ & = \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{a-2} \frac{t}{1+t^{2}} \ dt \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}}{1+t^{2}} \ dt \\ &=  \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)}  \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{v^{\frac{a}{2}-1}}{1+v} \ dv \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \frac{1}{2} B \left(\frac{a}{2}, 1- \frac{a}{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \frac{\pi}{2} \csc \left(\frac{\pi a}{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{w^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a-1)} \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2} \right)}{\sin (\pi a)} \\  &= w^{a-2} \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a) \cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2} \right)}{\Gamma(a-1)} \\ &= w^{a-2} \ (a-1) \Gamma(1-a) \cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2} \right)  \\ &=- w^{a-2} \  \cos \left(\frac{\pi a}{2} \right) \Gamma(2-a) \end{align}$$

which is the answer given by Wolfram Alpha

If you want to be more rigorous, integrate by parts at the beginning and choose $1+ \sin u$ for the antiderivative of $\cos u$. Then when you switch the order of integration, it's easily justified by Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: It seems the result is correct but I wonder, does the integral really converge? Let say we take $a=\dfrac13$ and $w=1$, what is the value of integral?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey It converges if $a$ is between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Now that makes sense. +1. Anyway, I have the answer for this integral but it involves $i^{\ a-2}$, where I use $i^{\large\ a-2}=e^{\large-\frac{i\pi(2-a)}{2}}$. It does give the same solution as yours.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks. I think I know the approach to which you're referring. As far as I know, the justification for that approach requires contour integration because when you make a complex substitution, you are no longer integrating on the real line.

Comment: Indeed you're correct but I use that approach when I was a Physics student and my prof(s) never complaint about that. I think that is the different between physics and math. :D

Answer (score 1):

The first example can be tackled using the expression of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in conjunction with [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula). The second, by differentiating twice under the integral sign, and then solving the resulting functional differential equation, in a manner quite similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402) example.

Comment: By the second one, do you mean by differentiating with respect to $a$? I think it's good idea but it generates divergent integral $\int\cos(ax)dx$... what did I miss?

Comment: Replace the upper limit with a parameter, and use a technique similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/178728/6) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/638940/2).