# Integrate this without using methods from Complex Analysis

Tags: calculus

Could anybody integrate this without using methods from Complex Analysis?

$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}dx
$$

Comment: Write $$h(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin (\omega x)}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,dx$$ and recognise a(n inverse) Fourier transformation (modulo constants). [I'm not saying that is necessarily easy, I'd use the residue theorem.]

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), in conjunction with [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), since $\dfrac d{da}\cos(ax)=-x\sin(ax)$. Then check out the many answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402), and try to imitate them.