# How to do integration of this?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x \sin x }{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + b^2)}dx\quad\quad a > b > 0$$

I have no idea how to compute this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if helps but I would start with partial fractions:
$$\int\frac{x \sin x }{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + b^2)}dx=\int\frac{x \sin x }{(a^2-b^2) (b^2+x^2)}dx+\int\frac{x \sin x }{(b^2-a^2) (a^2+x^2)}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- Use [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).
- [Evaluate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402) $~J(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{x^2+n^2}dx,~$ and then express the integral(s) in terms of $J'(k)$.

Answer (score 1):

notice the integrand is an even function, so you may take half of the integral along the entire real axis. since, as a function of a complex variable, it is also $O(|z|^{-2})$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$, the integral round a large semicircle $\rightarrow 0$, so you may use the residue theorem with poles $z=bi$ and $z=ai$

this gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x \sin x }{(x^2 + a^2)(x^2 + b^2)}dx = \frac{\sinh b - \sinh a}{(b^2-a^2)}\pi 
$$