# Evaluating $\int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{e^{-i p x / h}}{x^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to figure out this integral but cannot figure out the right substitution 
$$
\int^\infty  _{-\infty} \frac{e^{-i p x / h}}{x^2 + a^2}dx 
$$

Comment: I think you can find the value by consider the contour integral over a semi-circle living in $\{y\ge 0\}$ with radius $r$ and let $r\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find a wave function in the momentum representation. I believe you'll need to consider the two cases $p/h > 0$ and $p/h < 0$ separately if you're doing contour integration.

Comment: What is $i$, in your integral?

Comment: Mathematica gives the following:

$$\int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{e^{-i p x / h}}{x^2 + a^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\pi e^{-\frac{ap}{h}}}{a}$$

With $\frac{p}{h}\in\mathbb{R}\space\space\text{&&}\space\space\Re(a)\ne 0\space\space\text{&&}\space\space\left(\Re(a^2)\ge 0\space||\space a^2\notin \mathbb{R}\right)$

Comment: I get the same result from Mathematica, except with $|p/h|$. (Assuming $p/h$ is real.) It is clear from the original integral that the result must be even in $p/h$.

Comment: @JanEerland $i$ is the imaginary value $i$, sorry for forgetting to say that. I got the same thing with mathematica, but was looking for what substitution to do in order to do this by hand. I don't know contour integration but I should be definitely learn them.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{align}
I(\alpha,k) 
&= \int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{e^{-i  \alpha x}}{x^2 + k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{1} \\
&= \int^{\infty} _{-\infty} \frac{e^{i  \alpha x}}{x^2 + k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{2} \\
&= \frac12\int^{\infty} _{-\infty} \frac{e^{i \alpha  x} + e^{-i \alpha x}}{x^2 + k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{3} \\
&= \int^{\infty} _{-\infty} \frac{\cos \alpha x}{x^2 + k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x  \tag{4} \\
&= 2\int^{\infty} _{0} \frac{\cos \alpha x}{x^2 + k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x  \tag{5} \\
I(\alpha,k) 
&= \frac\pi {|k|} e^{-|\alpha|| k|}  \tag{6} 
\end{align}$$

Putting $\alpha = \dfrac ph$ and $k = a$ in $(6)$

> $$I\left(\frac ph,a\right)  = \int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{e^{-i  p x /h}}{x^2 + a^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
> = \frac \pi {|a|} e^{-|a||p/h|}$$

---

$\text{Explanation (2) :}$ Set $x \rightarrow -x$

$\text{Explanation (6) :}$ Using 
[$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \alpha x}{x^2 + k^2}  dx = \frac{\pi e^{-k\alpha}}{2k}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9409/190645)

Comment: Why are you able to set $x → -x$ and what are you doing to get (3)?

Comment: I believe Eq. (6) here is incorrect if $\alpha$ or $k$ are negative. There should be some absolute values taken. The reason I harp on this is that this looks like an attempt to calculate a quantum mechanical wave function in the momentum basis, and it will not be normalizable without the absolute values.