# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How does one compute the following integral?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx$$

---

I have tried extending $x$ to the complex plane then evaluating the following contour integral 
$$\oint_C \frac{\sqrt{x}e^{ix}}{1+x^2} dx$$
with the contour $C$ running along the whole real axis and then upper semicircle. I obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\big(\cos(x)+\sin(x)\big)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac\pi{e\sqrt2}$$
but not the original integral.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%3D0,infinity,sqrt(x)(sin(x))%2F(1%2Bx%5E2))) does not appear to give the solution in terms of regular constants.  It suggests a need to use error functions and the substitution $x\mapsto x^2$ followed by partial fractions on the denominator.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: The solution does not have to be regular constants, so long it is in special functions. I thought of that substitution before. How then do you deal with $\sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I think I know what to do. Do use the transformation then pick the contour to be around the first quadrant of the complex plane and take care of the singularity. I will try this later --- occupied right now.

Comment: Yeah.  And replace the sine with an exponential function (which is where we get our ole friend error function)

Comment: We need to use $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$

Comment: The result from WA seems to come from $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\big(\cos(x)-\sin(x)\big)}{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{\pi  \left(e^2 \text{erfc}(1)-\text{erfi}(1)\right)}{\sqrt{2} e}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Can you prove this equality?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Yes, but do you see a way to introduce the error function?

Comment: @Hans. No, I cannot and I am sorry about it, be sure !

Comment: @Hans: See [Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: @Lucian: How do you use it? Integration by parts does not give me much, neither does the contour integral over the octant.

Comment: @Hans: After a simple substitution, we are ultimately left with evaluating $J(i),~$ where $$J(a)~=~\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{x^2+x^{-2}}~dx,$$ which is nothing more than $-F'(a),~$ for $$F(a) ~=~ \int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{x^4+1}~dx,$$ which, in its turn, constitutes a solution to the differential functional equation $$F(a)+F''(a)=\dfrac12~\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a},$$ see [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) for more details.

Comment: @Lucian: Wow, I like this slick method of differentiation under integral! Would you like to put it up as an answer?

Comment: @Hans: Only if you promise not to ask me how to solve the aforementioned differential equation.

Comment: @Lucian: Hahaha, solving the differential equation may just give you back the original integral. Let me think about it. I like very much the new perspective though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Laplace transform of the sine function, we get $$ \begin{align}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin x}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \sin(x) \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(t) e^{-xt} \, \mathrm dt \, \mathrm dx  \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty}  \sin(t) \int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} \sin(x) e^{-tx} \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dx  \\ &= -\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(t) \int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{x} e^{-(t+i)x} \, dx \, \mathrm dt \\ &= -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \, \Im  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{(t+i)^{3/2}} \, \mathrm dt \tag{1}\\ &= - \sqrt{\pi} \,  \Im \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (t)}{\sqrt{t+i}} \, \mathrm dt \tag{2}\\ &=- \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \,  \Im \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{it}}{\sqrt{t+i}} \, \mathrm dt + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-it}}{\sqrt{t+i}} \, \mathrm dt \right). \end{align} $$

---

$(1)$ $\mathcal{L} \{\sqrt{x} \} (s) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 s^{3/2}}$ if $\Re(s) >0$

$(2)$ Integrate by parts.

---

Next, using the principal branch of the square root, let's integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{\sqrt{z+i}}, $$ around an infinitely large closed quarter-circle in the first quadrant of the complex plane.

Applying Jordan's lemma, we get

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{it}}{\sqrt{t+i}} \, \mathrm dt&=e^{i \pi/4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+1}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= 2 e^{i \pi/4} \, e \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-u^{2}} \, \mathrm du \tag{3} \\ &= 2 e^{i \pi/4} e \, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erfc} (1) \\ &= e^{i \pi/4} e \sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfc} (1). \end{align}$$

And by integrating the function $$g(z) = \frac{e^{-iz}}{\sqrt{z+i}} $$ around an infinitely large closed quarter-circle in the fourth quadrant of the complex plane (indented at $z=-i$), we get $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-it}}{\sqrt{t+i}} \, \mathrm dt &= \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{(1-t)e^{ i \pi /2}}} \, (-i \, \mathrm dt)  + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{(t-1)e^{-i \pi /2} }} \, (-i \mathrm \, dt) \\ &=  -e^{i \pi/4}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1-t}} \, \mathrm dt +  e^{ - i \pi /4} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t-1}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= -\frac{2 e^{ i \pi /4}}{e} \int_{0}^{1} e^{v^{2}} \, \mathrm dv + \frac{2e^{ - i \pi/4}}{e} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-w^{2}} \, \mathrm dw \tag{4} \\ &= -\frac{2e^{ i \pi /4}}{e} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erfi}(1) +  \frac{2 e^{ - i \pi /4}}{e}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}  \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e} \left(-e^{ i \pi /4} \operatorname{erfi}(1) + e^{-i \pi /4} \right). \end{align}$$

---

$(3)$ Let $u^{2} = t+1$.

$(4)$ Let $v^{2} = 1-t$ and let $w^{2} = t-1$.

---

Putting everything together, we have

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin x}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx  &= - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Im \left(e^{i \pi/4} e \sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfc}(1) + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e} \left(-e^{ i \pi /4} \operatorname{erfi}(1) + e^{-i \pi /4} \right) \right)\\ &= - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left(\frac{e \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}} \operatorname{erfc}(1) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{\sqrt{2}e} \operatorname{erfi}(1) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}e} \right)  \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}e} \left(1+ \operatorname{\color{red}{erfi}}(1) - e^{2} \operatorname{erfc}(1) \right). \end{align}$$

Comment: Bravo! +1 and accepted.

Comment: Would you please take a look at this more general problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2412725/64809 and see if a contour integral method, such as yours here, applies there? Thank you.

Comment: @Hans   I'm not sure about a contour integration approach, but there's a technique called the *method of brackets* that probably could be used to evaluate the general case.  It's basically a generalization of Ramanujan's master theorem.  I think the theory behind it is still a work in progress.  The original paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3356).  I've used the method to evaluate some integrals in the past, but it can get tedious.

Comment: Intriguing! Are you saying the method of the brackets method has not been proved yet? I look forward to seeing you apply it to that problem I point you to, nonetheless.

Comment: @Hans   I think parts of it have been proven.  Sometimes you end up with a hypergeometric series being evaluated at a point outside its disc of convergence.   That's when things get confusing.  Just for fun, I used the method to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1837429).

Answer (score 6):

For information :

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(y\:x)}{1+x^2} dx$ is the Fourier Sine Transform of $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}\quad $ In the Harry Bateman's Tables of Integral Transforms an even more general formula can be seen on page 71, Eq.28 , the Fourier Sine Transform of $x^{2\nu}(x^2+a^2)^{-\mu-1}$ :
$$\frac{1}{2}a^{2\nu-2\mu}\frac{\Gamma(1+\nu)\Gamma(\mu-\nu)}{\Gamma(\mu+1)}y \:_1\text{F}_2(\nu+1;\nu+1-\mu,3/2;a^2y^2/4)\:+\:4^{\nu-\mu-1}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\nu-\mu)}{\Gamma(\mu-\nu+3/2)}y^{2\mu-2\nu+1}\:_1\text{F}_2(\mu+1;\mu-\nu+3/2,\mu-\nu+1;a^2y^2/4)
$$
With$\quad y=1\quad;\quad a=1\quad;\quad \nu=1/4\quad;\quad \mu=0\quad\to\quad \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx =$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(5/4)\Gamma(-1/4) \:_1\text{F}_2(5/4;5/4,3/2;1/4)\:+\:4^{-3/4}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}\:_1\text{F}_2(1;5/4,3/4;1/4)
$$
The Generalized Hypergeometric $_1$F$_2$ function (don't confuse with the well-known 2F1) reduces to functions of lower level in the particular cases :

$\:_1\text{F}_2(5/4;5/4,3/2;1/4)=\sinh(1)$

$\:_1\text{F}_2(1;5/4,3/4;1/4)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4e}\left(e^2\text{erfi}(1)+\text{erf}(1) \right)$

and after simplification :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx = -\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh(1)+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\:e}\left(e^2\text{erfi}(1)+\text{erf}(1) \right)$$ 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\:e}\left(e^2\text{erfi}(1)+\text{erf}(1) +1-e^2\right)$$ 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\:e}\left(-e^2\text{erfc}(1)+\text{erf}(1) +1\right)$$
For the Hypergeometric $_1$F$_2$ function, see : http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/02/

About the functions erf, erfi, erfc, see : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html , http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html , http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html

Comment: Nice! +1. Where can I find the derivation of the transforms, at least this particular one, in Harry Bateman's Tables of Integral Transforms?

Comment: The Bateman's Tables of Integral Transforms (1954), is a extensive compilation of equations of integral transforms, without reference. Sorry, I have no more information.

Answer (score 1):

My goal is to prove 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\:e}\left(-e^2\text{erfc}(1)+\text{erf}(1) +1\right)$$
as stated in @JJacquelin's answer. My following attempt falls short of that. But it does provide an equivalent integral with much faster convergence.

Take the contour integral $$2\oint_C \frac{z^2e^{iz^2}}{1+z^4} dz$$
with contour $C$ run along the real axis from $0$ to $R$, trace the circle $Re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ running from $0$ to $\frac\pi 4$, then roll back to the origin along $xe^{i\frac\pi 4}$ with $x$ running from $R$ to $0$ while circumventing around the point $e^{i\frac\pi 4}$ clockwise with radius $\delta>0$. The integral on the octal circle vanishes as $R\to\infty$. We have
$$\oint_C \frac{z^2e^{iz^2}}{1+z^4} dz=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{ix^2}}{1+x^4} dx-e^{i\frac34\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-x^2}}{1-x^4}dx+\cdots$$

(to be continued)