# Is it possible to compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$ using ODE?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

**My question is:**

> Is it possible to compute the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$ using ODE?

**My trial:**
Let 
$$
I(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-bx}\frac{\cos ax}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
then by Dominant Convergence theorem, $I(a,b)$ is continuous on $[0,2] \times [0,1]$. So we only need to compute $I(1,0)$. Fix any $b\in (0,1]$, we can get the following ODE:
$$
I(a,b)-I^{''}_{aa}(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-bx}\cos ax \mathrm{d}x=\frac{b}{a^2 + b^2}
$$
I have difficulty to proceed. It seems hard to solve this second order ODE. Or any other method using ODE to compute this?

Thank you!

Comment: See this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**. By setting
$$
f(s):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s\cos x}{s^2+x^2}\:dx, \qquad s>0,
$$ one may prove that
$$
f''(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\left(\frac{s\cos x}{s^2+x^2}\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s\cos x}{s^2+x^2}\:dx=f(s)
$$ where we have used integration by parts twice. Thus, by using a standard solution of the linear ODE,
$$
y''(s)=y(s) 
$$ one gets$$
y(s)=c_1e^s+c_2e^{-s}
$$ then one ends up with

> $$
> \int_{0}^\infty \frac{s\cos x}{s^2+x^2}\:dx=\frac \pi2 e^{-s},\qquad s>0.
> $$

The sought integral is obtained by putting $s=1.$

Comment: how does one solve for $c_1,c_2$. One value of s could be $0$ what should be the other value

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Let $s \to \infty$, it gives $c_1=0$, then use $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\:dx=\frac \pi2$ to obtain $c_2$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa How to use integrate by part here? Thank you!

Comment: @EdwardWang I'm really busy these days, when I've time I will provide some details. Thank you.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thanks!

Comment: Please, check the fact that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+x^2}\right)=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+x^2}\right).$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh I see. Thanks a lot. And wish you happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Let’s consider the following integral parameterised by $y$.
$$
I(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ( xy)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)},\quad \textrm{ where }y\ge 0.
$$
Then we find the 1st and 2nd derivatives of $I(y)$ to set up a differential equation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I^{\prime}(y)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (x y)}{1+x^2} d x \\
& I^{\prime \prime}(y)=-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (x y)}{1+x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Combining them yields
$$
-I^{\prime \prime}(y)+I(y)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x y)}{x} d x=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
With the initial conditions $I(0)=0, I’(0)=\frac \pi2$ gives the general solution of
$$I(y)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ( xy)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-e^{-y}\right) $$
Differentiating $I(y)$ w.r.t. $y$ yields
$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (x y)}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(I (y))=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-y}\,}
$$
In particular, when $y=1$, $$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{\pi}{2e} } $$