# Evaluating $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2} dx$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2} dx$$
>
> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} dx$$

How do I evaluate these two integrals? Are the approaches very different?

I seem to get lost while substituting.

Comment: The first is easy: note that the sine is an odd function.

Comment: The first one is an odd function, over a symmetric interval...

Comment: @KennyLau The limit is only up to $\pi$ here, so I don't think it's necessarily the same

Comment: @Dylan retracted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ without using complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit)

Comment: @LutzL As I just said before, it's *not* the same integral. The limit only goes to $\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin$ is odd, the first integral reduces down to

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}{\rm~d}x=0$$

For the second integral, note that:

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{2i}\left[\frac1{x-i}-\frac1{x+i}\right]$$

And that$\newcommand{\cint}{\operatorname{Ci}}\newcommand{\sint}{\operatorname{Si}}$

\begin{align}\int_a^b\frac{\cos(x)}{x+c}{\rm~d}x&=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}\frac{\cos(x-c)}x{\rm~d}x\\&=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}\frac{\cos(x)\cos(c)+\sin(x)\sin(c)}x{\rm d}x\\&=\cos(c)(\cint(b+c)-\cint(a+c))+\sin(c)(\sint(b+c)-\sint(a+c))\end{align}

where $\cint$ and $\sint$ are [trigonometric integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

And so, we reach a final closed form of:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^2}{\rm~d}x=2\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^2}{\rm~d}x\\=i\big[\cos(i)(\cint(\pi+i)-\cint(\pi-i))-\sin(i)(\sint(\pi+i)+\sint(\pi-i))\big]$$

where we use some basic symmetries of $\cint$ and $\sint$ (even and odd, respectively).

If you wish to take it one step further, you'll get

$$\cos(i)=\cosh(1)=\frac{e+e^{-1}}2\\\sin(i)=i\sinh(1)=\frac{e-e^{-1}}2i$$

Comment: Simply B.A. - tell me if you answered this question then why voted to close it? Thanks for answer, +1 but then why close it?

Comment: @samjoe Oh yeah, I meant to mention that at the beginning of my answer but totally forgot about it. I'll close any question which lacks a certain amount of context regardless, but I had the urge to answer anyway since there didn't appear to be a good duplicate and the other answerers weren't coming up with much to answer the question.

Comment: Ok I respect your opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

The first integral is obviously zero by parity, and the second integral is not an elementary integral but depends on the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) functions.  On the other hand, numerical approximations are simple to derive, since

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{(\pi-x)^2}\right)\,dx $$
and over $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we have $\cos(x)\approx 1-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$, for instance.
 The second integral is approximately $\frac{11}{9}$.