# Revealing $e$ in real integrals without $e$ or $e^x$ in the integrand

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, examples-counterexamples

I've observed that certain **real integrals** yields elements not present within the integrated function itself. For instance, integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ produces $\ln$, and specific definite integrals of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ involve $\pi$. Then, I'm seeking a definite or indefinite integral whose
result contains $e$, despite the absence of $e$ or $e^x$ in the integrated function. Could you provide such an example or why it might not be possible?

Comment: @Mariano I presume this refers to integrating over cycles in an *algebraic* curve or variety?

Comment: A famous example, Laplace integral:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos bx}{a^2+x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2a} \mathrm{e}^{-ab},
$$
where $a,b>0$. Proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-with).

Comment: But in fact, trigonometric functions and exponential functions have a very profound connection. I'm not sure if this meets the OP's criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this integral from [this](https://t.me/math_www) Telegram channel

for $b \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\cos\bigg(x \sqrt{x^2+b^2}\bigg)dx = \frac{ \sqrt{2\pi}}{4} e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}} $$

---

Proof :

[image]

There are many such examples in this channel it took me under a minute to find this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't think it is possible to have $e$ without $\sin x , \sinh x$ etc

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well the question is not clear enough whether  trig function are allowed or not. I found tons of examples of integral of trig function that  have in the result of integration..

Comment: Nice answer. Another example is [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-with).